# Function call never stops while changing the component through route

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this angular component file

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  updateValue() {
    // getting api data from the backend
  }

  ngOninit() {
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.updateValue()
    }, 5000)
  }
}
```

Now what is happening here that, when i navigate to different component, my `setinterval` keeps running and fetches data from the backend. Is there any solution for this or angular works this way. I want that when I navigate to other component, the setInterval should stop automatically.

Additionally - I am navigating from child component to parent component

ie from `/home/dashboard ----->/home`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to `this.interval` and use the `ngOnDestroy` handler to stop the interval when the user navigates away via `clearInterval`.

https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.updateValue()
  }, 5000)
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.interval) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool ,that worked.I think ,I should start taking ,angular life cycle hooks seriously :P

Answer (score 0):

why not use rxjs timer?

```
isAlive=true;
ngOnInit()
{
  timer(0,5000).pipe(
    takeWhile(()=>this.isAlive),
    switchMap(()=>{
       return myService.getData()
    }).subscribe(res=>{
       //here you has the data from your service
    })
}
ngOnDestroy()
{
    this.isAlive=false;
}
```